# Android-x86 VirtualBox TSC calibration failed

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86

I'm trying to install Android-x86 4.2 with virtualbox on my pc. I followed a few tutorials from google and everything went quite well. After the installation, When I ran the virtual device, it gives me the Grub bootloader screen. After selecting the Android-x86 4.2 from the menu, rather than booting the android device, it takes me to the terminal. Now I know a few linux commands and I checked the directory and I can see that android File system is there. But I'm not sure why it isn't booting directly to the GUI. Here is the snapshot of the terminal:

[image]

I really need this to work for development purposes.

**Please ignore that Android Kitkat title at the top. I wanted to go with Android Kitkat but decided to work with jellybean either**

Comment: Your question title doesn't really have anything to do with the question. Also, what were you expecting to happen? What "few tutorials"?

Comment: Solved. Thanks for your criticism.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what fixed it (on a Mac). In settings under display I increased the video memory to 128MB and I enabled 3D acceleration. And make sure your Graphics Controller is set to "VMSVGA".

Syed if you remember how you solved it, it would be great if you could post it here. Thanks mate